# Flutter Geolocator plugin - Live location tracking not working when the device is idle and screen is turned off

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, geolocator

I am trying to implement a live location tracking feature in my flutter project (A B2B app for managers and Supervisors to track their technicians). I am using the [Geolocator](https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator) plugin. But right now I am unable to fetch the location when the device is held stationary and the app is in the background.

In iOS, there is no property for setting the interval duration. In Android we can set the interval duration but it is not working when we set the distance filter.

Is there any work around for this?

Comment: What accuracy have you requested? If you have requested `best` location accuracy then you should receive a location update every second, even if the user isn't moving.

Comment: @Paulw11 I have requested bestForNavigation location accuracy.

Comment: @Paulw11 I have changed it to `best` location accuracy. Now I am receiving a location update every 1 minute. Is there a way to configure this time interval ?

Comment: No. best or best for navigation (but don't use that because you aren't navigating) will deliver location updates at a rate of about 1Hz, but it may be affected by poor GPS (are you indoors)? For your use case you may want to look at using significant location change.   It uses much much less battery power and provides updates when the user moves about 500m.